# verifying username and password saved in a txt file Java

Tags: java, authentication

When someone registers, the username, and password is saved in a .txt file.
The code below verifies each line to check if the username and password exist in the file.

However, I don't want it to work this way because it gets a username with a random password...
I need it to verify both username and password for each user registered, any help?
(I'm using NetBeans)

```
public boolean isCustomer(){
    boolean isFound = false;
    String record = null;
    FileReader in = null;
    try{
        in = new FileReader ("login.txt");
        BufferedReader bin = new BufferedReader(in);
        record = new String();
        while ((record = bin.readLine()) != null)
        {
            if (NameTextField.getText().contentEquals(record))
                isFound = true;
            if (jPasswordField.getText().contentEquals(record))
                isFound = true;
        }

    bin.close();
    bin = null;
 }catch(IOException ioe){
    NameTextField.setText("IOProblem");
 }   
  return isFound;
}
```

---

The login.txt looks like this (username, then password and "$$$" as a separator):

```
Joe

656451asda

$$$

Robert

123456hbb

$$$

Tracey

56464999abc

$$$

Celia

abc1234897

$$$
```

Comment: Could you please show how the file login.txt looks like? On odd lines you have usernames and passwords on even lines? Have you considered changing the format of the file?

Comment: I haven't considered another option, which other ones?

Comment: A best format would be keeping username and passwords on the same line, as in Unix password files:
Joe:656451asda\n
Robert:123456hbb

Answer (score 1):

This ...

```
if (NameTextField.getText().contentEquals(record))
    isFound = true;
if (jPasswordField.getText().contentEquals(record))
    isFound = true;
```

Means that if you find either the user name OR the password in the text file, it will return true.  I'm pretty sure you don't want to do this.

Better to use two flags (`foundUser` and `foundPassword` for example) which you can set as required and then `return foundUser && foundPassword`

**Updated from feedback**

When checking the username/password values, you need to make sure that the password you are trying to match is being matched against the user, something like...

```
if (foundUser && jPasswordField.getText().contentEquals(record)) {
    foundPassword = true;
    break; // No need to compare any more details...
} else {
    foundUser = false;
}
if (NameTextField.getText().contentEquals(record)) {
    foundUser = true;
}
```

**Updated**

As a side note, you really shouldn't get using [`JPasswordField#getText`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPasswordField.html#getText%28%29) as it is a security risk.  You should be using [`JPassword#getPassword`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPasswordField.html#getPassword%28%29) and using [`Arrays.equals(char[], char[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals%28char%5b%5d,%20char%5b%5d%29) to compare them.

This, obviously raises issues with how you read the data from the text file as well.

(Mind you, having the username/passwords in a text file is probably a larger security risk :P)

Comment: But even with this correction you are checking the username among all usernames and the password among all password. But you are not checking that they correspond each other

Comment: @manu-fatto I hope the update fixes it - Thanks for the catch!

Comment: thanks you so much! I got it working, needs a few tweaks now but excellent help! :D

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in other answers there are many issues you should consider:

1. you should not store plain passwords. Compute a hash from the password and store the hash.
2. if possible use a database instead of a text file
3. if you cannot use a database store the username/password information on a single line of text. Here is a format which is similar to the one used in Unix password files:

   ```
   joe:fjckdsoij48738423
   marian:fjccoekrnvn3iernci3en
   mrbean:fjd84jfn4u48fu4nf
   ```

when you want to check a password (the hash of the password in view of point 1) you can read the password file line by line. Split the line on the occurence of the first ':' character to find username and password. Compare with user provided data.

Answer (score 0):

You should really be using a database for this.

If not the next best thing would be to scan in the file and use a Map with the username as the key. However you would still need to update the file accordingly in-case your program crashes.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the same boolean for a username and password. Once it finds one it will be set to true, and it doesn't matter if it finds the other (which is wrong, they both need to be there!).

I would set it up this way:

```
private String getUsername(String filename) {
    // 1. Open up the file.
    // 2. Return the String.
}

private String getPassword(String filename) {
    // Basically the same, but return the password.
}
```

Then, in isCustomer() you can do this:

```
String username = getUsername(filename);
String password = getPassword(filename);
return (username != null) && (password != null); // makes sure they're both there.
```

(Also, you really shouldn't be storing this in an unencrypted text file. That's a very bad idea and is something you NEED to learn if you want to be a programmer.)

Answer (score -1):

Put username and password in the same line of text.

Comment: That solution, though it works, skirts the logic error in the code and isn't much more than a kludge.